# File partition on daily basis in the filestreamsink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to use the file partition in the filestreamsink connector. but i tried using the timestamp as mentioned below. but i'm not getting. please correct my implementation or suggest alternative way

Kafka Connect Sink Connector Configuration

```
name=your-file-sink-connector
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
```

Kafka Topic and Output Directory

```
topics=your-kafka-topic
file=/path/to/output/directory/data
```

Partition files based on message timestamp

```
transforms=TimestampRouter
transforms.TimestampRouter.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter
transforms.TimestampRouter.topic.format=your-topic-${timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd}
transforms.TimestampRouter.timestamp.format=yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: and also i try this code :- 
name=your-file-sink-connector
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1

topics=your-kafka-topic
file=/path/to/output/directory/data

# Rotate files daily (in milliseconds)
rotate.interval.ms=86400000

# Optional: Include a timestamp in the file name
file.filename.format=your-topic-${topic}-${timestamp}

# Other configuration options as needed

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with FileStreamSink. Only HDFS/S3 Connector from Confluent can do filepath time "partitions" (it includes a custom `Partitioner` interface for this exact purpose).

`rotate.interval.ms` is not a property included in the FileStreamSink from Apache.

`TimestampRouter` only changes the topic name *per record*, not creates file directories